# Exposing the AnyConnect HTTPS service to outside network

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn, anyconnect

We have a Cisco ASA 5505 with firmware ASA9.0(1) and ASDM 7.0(2). It is configured with a public ip address, and when trying to reach it from the outside by HTTPS for AnyConnect VPN, we get the following log output:

```
6   Nov 12 2012 07:01:40        <client-ip> 51000   <asa-ip>    443 Built inbound TCP connection 2889 for outside:<client-ip>/51000 (<client-ip>/51000) to identity:<asa-ip>/443 (<asa-ip>/443)
6   Nov 12 2012 07:01:40        <client-ip> 50999   <asa-ip>    443 Built inbound TCP connection 2890 for outside:<client-ip>/50999 (<client-ip>/50999) to identity:<asa-ip>/443 (<asa-ip>/443)
6   Nov 12 2012 07:01:40        <client-ip> 51000   <asa-ip>    443 Teardown TCP connection 2889 for outside:<client-ip>/51000 to identity:<asa-ip>/443 duration 0:00:00 bytes 0 No valid adjacency
6   Nov 12 2012 07:01:40        <client-ip> 50999   <asa-ip>    443 Teardown TCP connection 2890 for outside:<client-ip>/50999 to identity:<asa-ip>/443 duration 0:00:00 bytes 0 No valid adjacency
```

We finished the startup wizard and the anyconnect vpn wizard and here is the resulting configuration:

```
Cryptochecksum: 12262d68 23b0d136 bb55644a 9c08f86b 
: Saved
: Written by enable_15 at 07:08:30.519 UTC Mon Nov 12 2012
!
ASA Version 9.0(1) 
!
hostname vpn
domain-name office.<redacted>.com
enable password <redacted> encrypted
passwd <redacted> encrypted
names
ip local pool vpn-pool 192.168.67.2-192.168.67.253 mask 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
!
interface Ethernet0/3
!
interface Ethernet0/4
!
interface Ethernet0/5
!
interface Ethernet0/6
!
interface Ethernet0/7
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.68.250 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address <redacted> 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name office.<redacted>.com
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.68.0 255.255.255.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart warmstart
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal DES
 protocol esp encryption des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal 3DES
 protocol esp encryption 3des
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES
 protocol esp encryption aes
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES192
 protocol esp encryption aes-192
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256
 protocol esp encryption aes-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1 md5
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal AES256 AES192 AES 3DES DES
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto map inside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP
crypto map inside_map interface inside
crypto ca trustpoint _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 enrollment self
 subject-name CN=vpn
 proxy-ldc-issuer
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ca certificate chain _SmartCallHome_ServerCA
 certificate ca 6ecc7aa5a7032009b8cebcf4e952d491
    <redacted>
  quit
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
 certificate f678a050
    <redacted>
  quit
crypto ikev2 policy 1
 encryption aes-256
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 10
 encryption aes-192
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 20
 encryption aes
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 30
 encryption 3des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 policy 40
 encryption des
 integrity sha
 group 5 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 86400
crypto ikev2 enable outside client-services port 443
crypto ikev2 remote-access trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
telnet timeout 5
ssh 192.168.68.0 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh timeout 5
console timeout 0
vpn-addr-assign local reuse-delay 60

dhcpd auto_config outside
!
dhcpd address 192.168.68.254-192.168.68.254 inside
!
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 inside
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint0 outside
webvpn
 enable outside
 enable inside
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-win-3.1.01065-k9.pkg 1
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-linux-3.1.01065-k9.pkg 2
 anyconnect image disk0:/anyconnect-macosx-i386-3.1.01065-k9.pkg 3
 anyconnect profiles GM-AnyConnect_client_profile disk0:/GM-AnyConnect_client_profile.xml
 anyconnect enable
 tunnel-group-list enable
group-policy GroupPolicy_GM-AnyConnect internal
group-policy GroupPolicy_GM-AnyConnect attributes
 wins-server none
 dns-server value 192.168.68.254
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev2 ssl-client 
 default-domain value office.<redacted>.com
 webvpn
  anyconnect profiles value GM-AnyConnect_client_profile type user
username <redacted> password <redacted> encrypted
tunnel-group GM-AnyConnect type remote-access
tunnel-group GM-AnyConnect general-attributes
 address-pool vpn-pool
 default-group-policy GroupPolicy_GM-AnyConnect
tunnel-group GM-AnyConnect webvpn-attributes
 group-alias GM-AnyConnect enable
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:12262d6823b0d136bb55644a9c08f86b
: end
```

**Clearly we are missing something, but the question is, what?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have a route back to the remote host accessing the VPN. You need to add a static route for all traffic back to the providers gateway address:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 <your default internet gateway>
```

That would cause the "No valid adjacency" message in the log. Hope that helps, let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

NAT? And don't forget to exclude the VPN pool from being NATted back out, as IPSEC needs the IP address intact, or it will be confused as to what traffic to encrypt and will therefore do nothing.